# Disable default multitouch gestures in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, libinput

I was using Linux Mint with libinput gestures. Now I am working on an Ubuntu device. However, when I try to run libinput gestures, Ubuntu mixes them with the default gestures. When I swipe up with three fingers it switches to the right workspace and opens activities at the same time. When I swipe down it switches to the left workspace and turns back to the normal. I just want to disable default multigestures by the Ubuntu. I could not find any setting about it. All the questions on this topic are either unanswered or too old.

Comment: I really need this because my right hand has problems that cause me to accidentally make two finger taps on my touchpad when I am trying to make a single finger tap.